# if you have convex set how can i prove that the function is concave

Tags: microeconomics

Let $x$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}_+^n$ and $θ$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}_+^n$ be the vectors of choice variables and parameters.

Consider the problem max $f(x)$ for $x$ where $f:\mathbb{R}_+^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $(x,θ)$ belongs to a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}_+^{n+k}$, if $S$ is convex and $f(x)$ is concave then the value of function of the problem $φ(θ)$ is a concave function.

I have this proof.the question is since $S$ is a convex set $(\bar{X}, \bar{Θ})=[λ'x+(1-λ)x'',λθ'+(1-λ)θ'']$ belongs to $S$ for all $λ$ belongs $[0,1]$

Can I prove that $φ$ function is concave?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Mathematics SE.